# How to send daily emails in c#

Tags: c#

I want to make a C# program that will send a email everyday at a certain time. How would I go about this? I already understand how to send emails in C# but as far as scheduling goes i'm at a loss.

Comment: use windows task scheduler to run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of libraries like [Hangfire](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html)

or write a windows service that has a scheduler.